# Ampscript and deliverability

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, deliverability

Can AMPSCRIPT degrade email deliverability or send emails more easily into Spams ?

Thank you.

Ludivine

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No it can’t. Ampscript is rendered server side hence only lives in the marketing cloud execution environment. Therefore it never hits the client and doesn’t affect delivery. The content the ampscript pulls on the others and might

Comment: Being a smart aleck: Ampscript is not rendered but processed. Ampscript can render but its not being rendered itself.